# Best way to get data from another collection when rendering documents in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a Person collection in Firestore that has an array with ids that refer to another collection called tasks.
The tasks collection contains all the tasks that exist and the array in Person has specific tasks belonging to that person.

Person collection from a specific person:

```
Firestore-root
     |
     --- person (collection)
          |
          --- personId (document)
                 |
                 --- taskDoing (field) - Array type
                        |
                        --- (tasksId) 0 - FEFEveDoZOv7WFsQLQvP
                                      1 - DEDSFgefeOv7WFsQLQvP
                                      2 - Wffw3f3333f7WFsQLQvP
```

Task collection:

```
Firestore-root
     |
     --- task (collection)
          |
          --- taskId (document)
                 |
                 --- title (field) - String type
```

So in Person collection I have an array with tasksIds and I want to retrieve task data from one specific Person, such as the title from the Task collection from only those ids.

How can I retrieve data?

I looked at the reference field but it can only specify one reference value at a time. What also might work is instead of storing only the id in Person, perhaps I could store the reference in the array?

Like:

```
task/FEFEveDoZOv7WFsQLQvP/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to display a person with their current tasks and all you want to display is the name of the task, for example, then I would most likely put that "dressing data" (the task name) into the person document so that I could render this screen with one network call. However, if you ever want to change the name of a task, this would be relatively expensive, because you'd have to change every person document that contained it. But if task names are permanent then I would almost certainly do this.

If there is lots of dressing data then you have to do some number crunching to see if it's more economical (in terms of engineering and dollar cost) to pack it all into the listing documents (the person document) or to fetch them separately. Just remember with Firestore (and NoSQL in general), your biggest costs will be read and write operations, not the size of documents.